# Add leading zeros in between constant and variable

Tags: abap, leading-zero

Any idea how to add zeros between sign `Q` and quantity?

I have sign `Q` and quantity as:

- example 1: Q10
- example 2: Q300

Code:

```
DATA variable TYPE c LENGTH 7 VALUE 'Q'
```

Expectation:

- from example 1: Q**0000**10
- from example 2: Q**000**300

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Many solutions. One of them (ABAP >= 7.02):

```
DATA(quantity) = 153.

DATA(variable) = |Q{ quantity WIDTH = 6 ALIGN = RIGHT PAD = '0' }|.

ASSERT variable = 'Q000153'.
```

NB:

- `|...|` is called a [String Template](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenstring_templates.htm)
- `{ ... }` inside a String Template, is called a [String Template Expression](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenstring_templates_expressions.htm)
- `WIDTH`, `ALIGN` and `PAD` are called the "[formatting options](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcompute_string_format_options.htm)" of string template expressions

Answer (score 0):

You need to split numeric and alfa numeric part. Then you can use below code numeric part:

```
write lv_text to lv_text right-justified.
translate lv_text using ' 0'.
```

Also you can use CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_INPUT function module for only number based variables.
Then concatenate two part.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use any QM DDIC data element in string templates utilizing its conversion like mkysoft suggested:

```
DATA qty TYPE vbeln VALUE '10' .

DATA(result) = 'Q' && CONV char6( |{ qty ALPHA = IN }| ).
```